# send file of form to php via ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to send file to php via ajax I have the code below but when I run it , It says that Undefined index: thefile
what is the problem?
 **HTML**

```
function postData(url){

    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange =  function(){

            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                var res = xmlHttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("upLoadName").textContent=res;

                }
                }

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("thefile", document.getElementById('thefile').files[0]);

                xmlHttp.send(formData);

}
```

and the form:

```
<form action="#" >
<input type="file" name="thefile" id="thefile"/>
<input type="button" name="Send"  value="send" onclick="postData('upLoad.php');"/>  </form>
```

**PHP**

```
echo json_encode($_FILES["thefile"]["name"]) ;
```

Comment: `$_FILES` must be empty. I don't see `multipart/form-data` anywhere.

Comment: @ PLB would u please explain me more?

Comment: add `xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");` before `onreadystatechange`

Comment: but it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is for the case you have multiple files, but should work for one file as well:

```
var formData = new FormData();
    jQuery.each($('#thefile')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    formData.append('thefile-'+i, file);
});
```

The first file can now be found at:

```
$_FILES['thefile-0']
```

Also be sure to set the content type.